# Closing Navigation Drawer After Selecting Item in MvxListView

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross, navigation-drawer

I use MvxListView as NavigationDrawer. Binding works fine, but it comunicates only with ViewModel. Since ViewModel cannot be aware of the coresponding View I have a problem because somehow I need to force View to close my NavigationDrawer.  I tried to do that on MvxListView_ItemSelected but it doesn't fire.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.EventSetListView);

    var sub = (EventSetListFrag)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.MyFrag);
    sub.ViewModel = _viewModel; 

    _drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.eventSetList_DrawerLayout);
    _drawer.SetDrawerShadow(Resource.Drawable.drawer_shadow, 3);
    _drawerList = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.eventSetList_NavigationList);


    SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    _drawerToggle = new DrawerToggle(this, _drawer,
            Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer, 
            Resource.String.drawer_open, 
            Resource.String.drawer_close);


        _drawer.SetDrawerListener(_drawerToggle);
        _drawerList.ItemSelected += _drawerList_ItemSelected;
}
```

And.. Drawer Layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/eventSetList_DrawerLayout"
...>

<fragment
    ... />

    <MvxListView
        android:id="@+id/eventSetList_NavigationList"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Collection; ItemClick SomeCommand;SelectedItem SelectedItem"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/navitem"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#101010"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#303030"
        android:listSelector="#9b2828" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Well I helped myself with MvxMessenger but I don't think it's a solution. Because when I start closing drawer my fragment redraws and shuts down drawer closing animation (sliding left)

Comment: Using the messenger - or using a presentation hint to the presenter - is what I was going to suggest. The redraw issues should just be UI issues - hopefully you will find other general Android Q&As here which can help with those issues.

Comment: Thnx on reply. I'm continuing my search.

Comment: Ah well, solution is simple. I made mistake to call SomeCommand (being RefreshCommand) on ItemClick. What I should be doing is call RaiseItemSelectedCommand in which i would just publish DrawerItemSelected message. View would catch this message and CloseDrawer. Then OnDrawerClosed ( see example https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/7948654 ) I should call my ViewModel.RefreshCommand.